# Jquery Selecting an element in a div based on text in a span

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

The Markup:

```
<div class="day">
        <span>1</span>
        <div class="icon-shop icon-blank"><p class="event-details" id="shop-1"></p></div>
        <div class="icon-eat icon-blank"><p class="event-details" id="eat-1"></p></div>
        <div class="icon-fun icon-blank"><p class="event-details" id="fun-1"></p></div>
        <div class="icon-scoop icon-blank"><p class="event-details" id="scoop-1"></p></div>
</div>
<div class="day">
        <span>2</span>
        <div class="icon-shop icon-blank"><p class="event-details" id="shop-2"></p></div>
        <div class="icon-eat icon-blank"><p class="event-details" id="eat-2"></p></div>
        <div class="icon-fun icon-blank"><p class="event-details" id="fun-2"></p></div>
        <div class="icon-scoop icon-blank"><p class="event-details" id="scoop-2"></p></div>
</div>
```

This is for a calendar and I am pulling in event data.

An example: If an event is on day 2 in the shop category , I then need to remove class .icon-blank from:

```
<div class="icon-shop icon-blank"><p class="event-details" id="shop-2"></p></div>
```

needs to become

```
<div class="icon-shop"><p class="event-details" id="shop-2"></p></div>
```

This is what im trying to do:
I have the event on day 2 in the shop category.

```
var cat = 'shop';
var day = '2';

    $(".day").find("span:contains('"  + day + "') > .icon-" + cat).removeClass('icon-blank');
```

The code above I am trying to select the proper day div(the day with a span with the text "2" and then select the div .icon-shop within that day. If that makes any sense at all lol.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `:contains()`, because `12` contains `2`, too. Better write a small filter:

```
var cat = 'shop';
var day = '2';

$("div.day span").filter( function() { 
  return $.trim( $(this).text() ) == day;
}).parent("div").find("div.icon-"+cat).removeClass('icon-blank');
```